# ASP.Net FormView won't update with Response.Redirect code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I have a fairly simple FormView control I'm using with ASP.Net/C#. My issue is when I use the code to redirect after the update/edit, the FormView won't actually perform the update, but, it will Redirect. I won't post all of the FormView code because it does update when I comment out the Redirect code. I think what I am asking is how to change the code to update while using the Redirect Code? Again, the update works fine when I don't do the Redirect! Is it possible the redirect is happening before the update can take place?

Code for Redirect

```
         <script runat="server">

    protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
       
        {
           Response.Redirect("redirect_main.aspx");
        }
    }


</script>

FormView1
          <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" onitemupdating="FormView1_ItemUpdating" DataKeyNames="req_submitted_key" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DefaultMode="Edit" >
                   <EditItemTemplate>
                    req_submitted_key:
                    <asp:Label ID="req_submitted_keyLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("req_submitted_key") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Role_job_title:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Role_job_titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Role_job_title") %>' />
                    <br />
                    requestname:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="requestnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("requestname") %>' />
                    <br />
                    submitted_by_name:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="submitted_by_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("submitted_by_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Submitted_by_email:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Submitted_by_emailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Submitted_by_email") %>' />
                    <br />
                    submitted_date:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="submitted_dateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("submitted_date") %>' />
                    <br />
                    submitted_by_comment:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="submitted_by_commentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("submitted_by_comment") %>' />
                    <br />
                    approved_denied:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="approved_deniedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("approved_denied") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes...it redirecting before the update. Take your redirect out of ItemUpdating and put it in ItemUpdated.

From: [DetailsView.ItemUpdatint Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemupdating?view=netframework-4.8)

**DetailsView.ItemUpdating Event**

> Occurs when an Update button within a DetailsView control is clicked,
> but before the update operation.

**DetailsView.ItemUpdated Event**

> Occurs when an Update button within a DetailsView control is clicked,
> but after the update operation.

[DetailsView.ItemUpdated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemupdated?view=netframework-4.8)

Your code should look like:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("redirect_main.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Maybe I need to read the article again but I don't see in that page where it explains how to prevent my issue that is occurring.

Comment: @user2209864 OK..I updated the answer....remove the redirect and put it in ItemUpdated.

Comment: I'll give that a try @user2209864

Comment: I read that this code will help but I get an Exception error on it! (does not contain a definition for Exception

if (e.Exception == null)

Comment: protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
       
        {
            Response.Redirect("redirect_main.aspx");
        }
    }

Comment: I have it in the itemupdating event. I've been researching this all day. It seems like a tremendous effort for something so small but I guess a lot of folks don't have to redirect!

Comment: I still have the issue.

Comment: @user2209864 It goes in ItemUpdated....not ItemUpdating. People redirect all the time...alot.

Comment: Can you send me a sample code snippet. I think it this point after so many hours some frustration has set it

Comment: Tried this
Line 56:         <div>
Line 57: 
Line 58:             <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" onitemupdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"    DataKeyNames="req_submitted_key" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="450px" >
Line 59:                 <EditItemTemplate>

And this
 protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)

But I get an error

Comment: Giving the code a try now. I'm also removing the  onitemupdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"  from the FormView code. 

        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"    DataKeyNames="req_submitted_key" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="450px" >

Comment: I have the following but the redirect does not work. The update to the table works without any issue but the redirect does not work.
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("redirect_main.aspx");
    }

Comment: This is what I have now:
<script runat="server">
 protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("redirect_main.aspx");
    }
</script>
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"  OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated" DataKeyNames="req_submitted_key" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="450px" >
I get the following Error message:
Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'FormView1_ItemUpdated' matches delegate 'FormViewUpdatedEventHandler'

Comment: This worked!

<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Approve_deny_confirm.aspx.cs" Inherits="echodevelopment.Approve_deny_confirm" %>
<script runat="server">
 void FormView1_ItemUpdated(Object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("redirect_main.aspx");
 }
</script>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"  OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated" DataKeyNames="req_submitted_key" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="450px" >